# How to get path of hardware RAID array in lsblk?

Tags: linux, raid, lsblk

I detect list of hardware arrays by next command:

```
lspci -vmm | sed -E -n '/RAID bus|SCSI controller/,/^ *$/p' | tr -d '\t'
```

Example:

```
Class:RAID bus controller
Vendor:Broadcom / LSI
Device:MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator]
SVendor:ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
SDevice:MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator]
Rev:05
NUMANode:0

Class:Serial Attached SCSI controller
Vendor:Intel Corporation
Device:C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit
SVendor:ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
SDevice:C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit
Rev:06
NUMANode:0
```

how can I find what is the path of each from above in `lsblk`?

Comment: Although not a 1:1 answer to your question, perhaps you find this useful. https://serverfault.com/questions/718654/can-i-detect-hardware-raid-infromation-from-inside-linux